# Typedefs for function pointer type

Tags: c++, function-pointers, typedef

I got a typedef function pointer type defined as

```
typedef double(*fun)(const eValue&);
```

why is this line throwing an error: missing type specifier -int assumed? and syntax error: missing , before '&'?

can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like `eValue` hasn't been declared in that scope.

Answer (score 1):

The reason likely is that `eValue` is undefined.

Assuming it is an `enum` (just guessing from its name) try

```
enum eValue;
typedef double(*fun)(const eValue&);
```